# How to use Linq to parse through XML easly - Need some sample code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqlxml

I am using XML Auto in my SQL Server to query data out.  I want to know how best to parse through the data that it provides.

My end goal is to provide a list of items with their values, but I don't know how many columns or what the names of the columns will be until at least the data is pulled form SQL at runtime.

Here is a sample XML

```
  <animals>
    <animal name="Pig">
      <meat>
        <name>Prosciutto</name>
      </meat>
      <meat>
        <name>Speck</name>
      </meat>
    </animal>
    <animal name="Cow">
      <meat>
        <name>Clod</name>
      </meat>
      <meat>
        <name>Brisket</name>
      </meat>
      <meat>
        <name>Tri-tip</name>
      </meat>
    </animal>
    <animal name="Chicken">
      <meat>
        <name>Drumstick</name>
      </meat>
    </animal>
  </animals>
```

How can I show this in a list, and perform Linq2SQL (or Linq2XML)?

Comment: Why LINQ in the first place? Does it have to be?

Comment: What are your columns? The animal. Do you want your list to be grouped by animal and meat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a list

```
var q = from x in doc.Descendants()
        select x.Value;
```

to select specific nodes, e.g. animals, do `doc.Descendants("animal")`

to select specific value, e.g. name of an animal do `select x.Attribute("name").Value`

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TdCWjE

Comment: How do I go one level deeper?

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
  var q = from x in doc.Descendants("animal")
                 select x;
  
  foreach(var x in q)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(x.Element("meat").Value);
  }